# Which wallet applications implement BIP38 - Private Key password encryption

Tags: wallet, bip38

I just learned about bip38 as it has to do with bitcoin private key encryption by putting a password to the key on the QR code. My question is which wallet apps support this decryption feature?

Comment: See:
[What is the current state of BIP 38 (encrypted paper wallet) integration with cell phone wallets?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/19842/what-is-the-current-state-of-bip-38-encrypted-paper-wallet-integration-with-ce)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bip38 QR password protection can be read by block chain.info wallets and on android it can be read by the mycellium wallet app. It will pop up a enter your password dialog box once you scan it.

Answer (score 3):

The paper wallet generator from [Bitaddress](https://www.bitaddress.org/) lets you encrypt with BIP38.

Comment: but how do you decrypt it?

Comment: That's on the same page: click the tab "wallet details", enter the encrypted private key, press view details, enter the BIP38 passphrase, and finally click decrypt BIP38.

Comment: i guess we'll have to wait until someone implements it into an application as no way is anyone going to type out a case sensitive private key! =)

Comment: There are ways of copy-pasting it. On bitaddress, use "hide art" to copy the private key.