# What is the current state of BIP 38 (encrypted paper wallet) integration with cell phone wallets?

Tags: private-key, encryption, paper-wallet, bip38

Given current implementations, is there a wallet that I can use to scan a private key, then enter in the password as a PIN, and the wallet will send from the key and sweep the rest onto a key generated from the phone?

Android, obviously.

Also, what's the state of BIP-38 integration with wallets in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/wallet/android-app) works well, exactly as you describe for BIP38 encrypted keys.

I switched to [Mycelium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mycelium.wallet) in late 2014 and have had good experiences since then.

> what's the state of BIP-38 integration with wallets in general?

It is actually quite good now.
Only obviously missing wallet is Armory: https://github.com/etotheipi/BitcoinArmory/issues/131

(Armory pioneered many of these ideas with its own implementations, but it is not yet using standards like BIP32 and BIP38 which came later)

One can also use [Bippy](http://bippy.org/) to work with BIP38 encrypted keys offline.

PS: I just added recommendations here for creating a paper wallet:
[How to download bitaddress.org to use offline?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22115/how-to-download-bitaddress-org-to-use-offline/22124#22124)

Answer (score 1):

[Mycelium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mycelium.wallet&hl=en) is a well-reviewed Android wallet that seems to meet the criteria you've described.