# How to download bitaddress.org to use offline?

Tags: security, offline, bitaddress.org, bip38

The site does not have a download option.

I can save the page using Google Crome by CTR-S, but the version I have saved in this way does not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update 2024 (10 years later):

bitaddress.org has not changed in 8 years and may contain bugs & outdated tech such as BIP38 encryption.

Instead, I recommend to use a modern BIP39 tool with a very good track record such as this:
https://github.com/iancoleman/bip39

You should do your research and ensure that you create the wallet on an offline system which is also (ideally) stateless like [TailsOS](https://tails.net/).  This will minimize (but not eliminate) the chances of malware being able to affect your wallets.

Once you have the downloaded files in a secure environment, ensure you properly check the gpg signature before loading the html file into a browser and using it to generate a paper wallet.

**Warning:**

Paper wallets generated in a browser may be fun and free, but they present many security risks, not least from the computer you are using.  Instead: consider using an Open Source mobile app or, if securing larger amounts, get a hardware wallet.

Comment: "Make your paper wallet and several prints (do not save a copy anywhere on the computer)." Can you save on a pendrive while not connected to internet - and never have that pendrive inserted when the computer is internet enabled?

Comment: You can do whatever you like, but if you are going to put it on a pendrive / usb stick, I'd suggest putting it inside a TrueCrypt encrypted file container.  One of the best parts of a paper wallet is that you can rest assured that the private keys are *nowhere at all* except on that piece of paper (and even then they are encrypted).  This means that an attacker *must* have physical access to that piece of paper to even begin an attack.  I do not know how crackable BIP38 is, but a lot of it will depend on the length of your password.

Comment: >      I do not know how crackable BIP38 is...  


I checked up on this, it is very safe, there is no concerns with the encryption itself.

Comment: _**Drag** the bitaddress.org.html file into your browser._ seriously? why not just double-click it?

Comment: **[PSA: For users of http://bitcoinpaperwallet.com](https://twitter.com/jonf3n/status/1062380032889368576)** Note, the website and all related business was sold to an unknown individual and is no longer being maintained at https://github.com/cantonbecker/bitcoinpaperwallet

Info on the website does not match the signed info on GitHub and provides no link to a new repo.

Comment: @JonathanCross: Is there a reason why you don't use PGP verification of the HTML file? Isn't this step necessary?