# How to generate a paper wallet?

Tags: wallet, security, paper-wallet, coldstorage, wallet-security

What do you find the best way to generate a paper wallet for BTC?

I've heard of this one: https://keybase.io/warp/warp_1.0.9_SHA256_a2067491ab582bde779f4505055807c2479354633a2216b22cf1e92d1a6e4a87.html

How can you be sure your address is not compromised?

Thank you!

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the procedure at [How to download bitaddress.org to use offline?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22115/how-to-download-bitaddress-org-to-use-offline) for creating a paper wallet on an offline / airgapped computer, you can be fairly certain that your private key will not be compromised during the process.  For more info, see https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/How_to_set_up_a_secure_offline_savings_wallet

Comment: Thank you! And I should do that from a TAILS USB right?

Comment: I don't think you need to use Tails.  If you're doing this on an airgapped (offline) computer, there is no networking involved, so no need to use Tails.  You could simply boot to a live OS image, such as Ubuntu.